# How to hide the default delete button in the first row of the tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to hide the default delete button in the `UITableView`s first row, and for the remaining cells, I want to show the default delete button in `UITableView`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to disable swipe to delete on the first row?

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the [tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:)

Answer (score 2):

Implement Table View delegate method `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

something like this:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL aReturnVal = YES;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        aReturnVal = NO;
    }

    return aReturnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement below table view delegate method to achieve it.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

below method also need to implement you can put your logic when row is being delete.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //put your delete logic here.
}
```